# Download/create address locator styles for Europe?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geocoding, geolocation, europe

Where can I find some address locator styles for European countries? or how can I create my own address locator that contains street, house number and city, and use their aliases?

PS. I have the book: Customizing Locators in ArcGIS 10

Comment: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dff63d09c79a44b8b3c63f2d90222e0e has information but the online version will be retired on 31 December 2013.

Comment: I see online server but I can`t find file to download...

Comment: You can build your own with the Technical Notes - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_an_address_locator/002500000013000000/

Comment: I know, but create own Locator Style is difficult (for me), so I'm looking for something finished (or good advice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless you find someone other than Esri that is willing to share locator styles with you, you are out of luck.

We have being building our own locators for Canadian style addresses, and even with enterprise developer support from Esri, it has not been easy.

The documentation is non-existent beyond the whitepaper, which is little help with actual customization. We've had a few questions answered, but allowing customized locators is not really the direction that are headed in, despite the ability to do so. They are also unwilling to share their locators styles (beyond the US ones), since this is a paid product that they offer (i.e. they don't want to give away details of their profit making locators).